# Pycharm (Mac) selecting a line

Tags: pycharm

Three ways that I know of:

1. triple click anywhere in the line
2. click line number in gutter
3. cmd+left move caret to start of the line, then cmd+shift+right

But 1 and 2 involve mouse clicking, 3 is a combo. Any real shortcut for selecting one line?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can [assign a keyboard shortcut](http://img801.imageshack.us/img801/6835/7d.png) to this action: **Select Line at Caret**.

Also note that Copy/Cut actions will work without any selection and will affect the whole line as if it was selected.

Comment: Thanks. BTW: how do you change the appearance of the window? I like that semi-transparent look, it's awesome

Comment: You will have to install Windows 7 for that Aero effect =)

Comment: Adding +1 mostly for the "copy without selection", even though the shortcut part is good as well

Answer (score 4):

I will give a chance to <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> It does not do the job at once, but in few clicks it can be very handy.

Answer (score 2):

Since there are already keymaps for moving a line up/down, duplicating a line, and deleting a line, the only other purpose I would select an entire line is for copying to a location too far for moving up/down. So, I use the `copy` command (accessibly by default with `Command-C` using PyCharm CE 2017.3 on mac), which has the nice behavior of automatically selecting and copy the entire line where the cursor is, as long as no text is currently selected.

Answer (score 0):

`shift` + `end` will select the line till the end of the line, so there's always:

`home` and then `shift` + `end`

(on Windows, but Mac is the same I guess?)

Comment: `shift` + `end` also works for **Linux**